# Issues retrieving Terraform output from remote state in Artifactory terraform-backend repository

Tags: terraform, artifactory

I'm encountering difficulties with my Terraform configuration, utilizing Artifactory's terraform-backend repository as the backend for storing tfstates.

Configuration Overview:

Terraform Backend: **remote: Artifactory | repository type: terraform-backend**
Terraform Version: **1.0.2**

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to effectively retrieve Terraform state or output from Artifactory in this specific scenario.

Thank you in advance!

I have explored two potential solutions to retrieve Terraform output from the state:

**1st Solution:** Attempting to obtain the output directly from the remote state.

**Problem:** I haven't found a corresponding Terraform command to achieve this.

**2nd Solution:** Downloading the tfstate from the Artifactory terraform-backend repository locally and executing the command: `terraform output -state=terraform.tfstate output-1`.

**Problem:** Downloading the file state.latest.json directly from the terraform-backend Artifactory results in a file containing state versions, rather than the expected tfstate content containing outputs.

Comment: in your 2nd solution that should work fine ... why do you need to download the state when you are doing `terraform output` ?  you should be able to do that just like you do any of the other TF commands